# Import JSON data into InfluxDB to update/overwrite value in bulk

Tags: import, influxdb

I am able to dump data to a file using curl. The output file is a JSON format file
It looks like this

```
{"results":[{"series":[{"name":"cpu"...
```

Now, I modified the JSON to replace some values. Mind you, I didn't change the format of the file.

Now, how can I post this back to influx to overwrite this record?

Comment: Maybe you could try to use Telegraf metrics exporter - it is part of InfluxDB family and it can parse JSON - https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/DATA_FORMATS_INPUT.md

Answer (score 0):

InfluxDB doesn't accept any form of JSON writes. You'd have to reconstruct line protocol from the JSON and then rewrite it back into the database.